# Probability of two cards of the same kind appearing twice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's suppose that there are $8$ cards $AABBBCCC$, and that we're choosing $3$ cards among them. Then, how can we find the probability that $2$ cards of the same kind appear?

The first computation I've made is how many ways we can choose two cards of the same kind: there are $3\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{1}$ different ways for the card $A$ to appear twice, $3\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{3}{3}$ different ways for the card $B$ to appear twice, $3\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{3}{3}$ different ways for the card $C$ to appear twice.

Then, our probability is $\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{1} + 2\big(\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{3}{3}\big)}{\binom{8}{3}} =\frac{38}{56} = \frac{19}{28}$.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: That seems quite low.  Easier, I expect, to compute the probability that you get one of each type.  Note:  the wording is not clear, are you excluding $3$ of a kind or not?

Comment: Imagine each card is distinct. So we have $A_1A_2B_1B_2B_3C_1C_2C_3$. Then there are $2\times 3\times 3=18$ ways to choose three distinct values, and $\binom 83=56$ ways to choose $3$ cards. Hence $\frac {18}{56}=\frac 9{28}$ probability of getting distinct values.  Meaning a $\frac {19}{28}$ chance that (at least) $2$ will match.  Easy to account for $3$ of a kind of you want.

Comment: The binomial symbol counts *unordered* selections.

Comment: **Clarification requested**: "Then, how can we find the probability that 2 cards of the same kind appear?" : Do you intend $\color{red}{\text{at least}}$ 2 cards of the same kind or $\color{red}{\text{exactly}}$ 2 cards of the same kind?

Comment: The problem does not mention order.  Of course, you can solve the problem by looking at ordered selections if you prefer.  Just be sure you do it consistently.

Comment: Note that $\binom{8}{3} = \frac{8!}{3!5!} = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5!}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 5!} = \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 8 \cdot 7 = 56$, so you should have obtained $\frac{38}{56} = \frac{19}{28}$.  That said, your explanation does not make sense since you seem to be considering the order of selection, which mysteriously disappeared in your actual calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want Pr of *at least* two cards of a kind, just compute
the complement of the Pr of getting one each of all $3$ kinds.

$Pr = 1 - \Large\frac{\binom21\binom31\binom31}{\binom83}= \frac{19}{28}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\text{Probability}={\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}}}.
$$
You must consider this problem as AA are two green balls, BBB are three blue balls, CCC are three red balls, and you need to extract from the box exactly the same two balls.

If we would like to change the problem statement to "at least twice", then the probability should be
$$
\text{Probability}={\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{3}{3} + \binom{3}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}}}.
$$

Comment: @Melz, the order is not important, at least the problem say nothing about the order.

Comment: @Melz, but the problem states the probability that 2 cards of the same kind appear.

Comment: @Melz, yes, you are right, If we would like to change the problem statement to "at least twice", then the probability should be ${\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}+ \binom{3}{3}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1} + \binom{3}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}}}$.

Comment: Thanks, I am so grateful!

Comment: @Melz, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, likewise!